# scala function not called from lambda function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda

I am new to scala and just understanding how can I transform via Map call. The foo function is not getting called. What is that I am missing ?

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Expt {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]")
                val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                val a1 = sc.parallelize(List((1,"one"),(2,"two"),(3,"three"))
                val a3 = a1.map(x => Expt.foo(x))
}

def foo(x: (Int,String)) : (Int,String) = {
        println(x)
        x
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't execute any action so map is never evaluated. Also println in map usually won't have visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

trigger computation using `collect` or `foreach` (do some action)

```
scala> val a1 = sc.parallelize(List((1,"one"),(2,"two"),(3,"three")))
a1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val a3 = a1.map(x => foo(x))
a3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:28

scala> a3.collect
(1,one)
(2,two)
(3,three)
res3: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((1,one), (2,two), (3,three))

scala> a3.foreach(_ => ())
(1,one)
(3,three)
(2,two)
```